# How to display multiple paragraphs

Tags: angularjs, json, database, paragraph

I need to show the profile overview which may or may not consist of multiple paragraphs of simple text.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 style="color:#26506D"><strong>Profile Overview</strong></h3>
        <p class="text-justify">{{Item.Consultant.ProfileOverView}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The user will enter the overview for themselves and that data will be displayed here, if I enter 2 paragraphs of text, then that is displayed as a single paragraph in the display page,

I guess the database doesn't store the data in the form of paragraphs it might be removing the line breaks, 
I need to show multiple paragraphs, any suggestions on how to do that.

Comment: Which database are you using? Did you try storing it as json?

Comment: @SajalS yes i am using sql and using json to store

Comment: store each paragraph value/text in array like Consultant = [{ProfileOverView : 'value'}] and use ng-repeat to display them.

Comment: thanks but just writing style:"white-space:pre-wrap" has solved my prob

Comment: You should list that as the answer and accept it, so that it's easier for others to use your solution. For reference: I'm storing a string in a text PostrgreSQL column, and the style fixed it for me.